# Transform the coordinate of xy pairs from 'data' to 'axes fraction'

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

#### A. Background

I was plotting Chloropleth plot with Python-matplotlib.
The `ax.text` or `ax.annotate` function hase some error, and I post here for help.

#### B. My problem

A. When I use the code below to add some string on the map:

```
ax.annotate("LOL",xy=(114.5,38.5), xycoords = 'data',fontsize = 15, 
                 fontstyle = 'italic',zorder =3) `
```

No matter what I change the *xypairs*, the string "LOL" always **located on the bottom-left position**. The figure shows like:

http://i4.tietuku.com/620a3bb6052d7859.png

B. Changing the xycoords type:

```
ax.annotate("LOL",xy=(0.4,0.6),xycoords='axes fraction',    
             fontsize = 15, fontstyle = 'italic',zorder =3,color = 'w')
```

The figure shows like this:

http://i11.tietuku.com/f1e175b427377160.png

#### C. My analysis

I think the problem may occur due to the projection setting. For the purpose of add a map scale, I choose `tmerc` projection:

```
map = Basemap(projection='tmerc', lon_0 =xxx, lat_0 = xxx,
             ellps = 'WGS84', llcrnrlon=xxx,llcrnrlat=xxx,urcrnrlon=xxx,
             urcrnrlat=xxx,lat_ts=0,resolution='i',suppress_ticks=True)
```

When I use `map = basemap(llcrnrlon=xxx ,llcrnrlat=xxx, urcrnrlon=xxx, urcrnrlat=xxx)`, `xycoords = 'data'`type works fine.

But my characters were based on the data point(which represent each polygon's district name), the `data` type is what I need to choose. So, I would like to learn some function which can change the xypairs in `data`type into `axes fraction` type. Then, the problem can be figured out!